# Convert Excel sheets to Pandas df's

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with one sheet name "info" as follows

```
Name Number
S1  50
S2  100
S3  400
```

This sheet give info about other sheet which I need to convert into pandas df's.
but, when I read this sheet and loop to create other df's. My code is also looking for a sheet name "Name" and thus breaking...any way to avoid this?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: As @aneroid said, please provide what you have already tried. It is much easier for us to help you out, if we can see what's you've already tried.

Comment: This is straight forward!. While you are looping, just skip the first entry in your loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a header row or skip the first row as mentioned in the comments.

```
df_info = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='info', header=0)
sheets = {}
for sheet_name in df_info['Name']:
    sheets[sheet_name] = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet_name, header=None)
```

[Pandas Read Excel Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)